# The last overload gave the following error

Tags: typescript, tsc, sequelize-typescript

I'm getting this error on build using tsc

> The last overload gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.
>
> 8 app.listen(port, (err) => {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:1033:5
>       1033     listen(handle: any, listeningListener?: () => void): http.Server;
>                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       The last overload is declared here.

My package json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-statsd": "^0.3.0",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
    "hashids": "^1.2.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.5.1",
    "nyc": "^13.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.7",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^1.1.0",
    "strong-error-handler": "^2.3.0",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.39",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.41",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.4",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
```

Can someone help?
thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you please post the actual code that causes the problem?

Comment: The callback function `app.listen(port, (err) => {})` doesn't take params `err` so you can just write `app.listen(port, () => {})`